# Split String based on the dot delimeter

Tags: java, regex, split, switch-statement

i'm working on a method that split a string based on the . delimiter, i have used the Pattern and Matcher classes, and get the start positions of the delimiter and stored them in an array and now i want to split the specified string based on those start positions, my problem is that when i tried the following code, the program goes forever (Infinite loop).

```
public void cutByRegex(){
     String outPut="";
     int i=0;
     int startIndex[]=new int[3];
     System.out.println("IP--->"+ip);
     Pattern p=Pattern.compile("\\.");

     Matcher m=p.matcher(ip);
     while (m.find()){
        startIndex[i]=m.start();
        i++;
        System.out.println("start: "+m.start());
     }
     System.out.println("StartIndices-->");
     for(int j:startIndex)
          System.out.println(j);
     for(i=0;i<startIndex.length+1;){
        switch(i){
        case 0:
        outPut+=ip.substring(i,startIndex[i]);
        i++;
        case 1:
           outPut+=ip.substring(startIndex[i]-1,startIndex[i]);
           i++;
        case 2:
           outPut+=ip.substring(startIndex[i]-1,startIndex[i]);
           outPut+=ip.substring(startIndex[i],ip.length());
           break;
        }
     System.out.println("group--->"+outPut);
     }    

    }
```

for example:
   the startIndex array contains 3,5,7
   i want to substring 127.1.1.254 
   from 0--->3
   from 4--->5
   from 6--->7
   from 8--->ip.length

Note:i know the built in method split() well, i want to do the job manually
   what mistakes i have done??

Comment: can you format the code properly please? Bit ahrd to read...

Comment: You are not incrementing `i` in `case 2:`.

Comment: First of all, why are you trying to make your own split() . Java has an inbuilt split method, u can use that. Secondly, inside the 2nd for loop, don't u need to increment i irrespective of which ever case that is ? Why increase it inside the  case block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have not used increment part in for loop i variable and case block 2**

Your code

```
    for(i=0;i<startIndex.length+1;){

      case 2:
         outPut += ip.substring(startIndex[i] - 1, startIndex[i]);
         outPut += ip.substring(startIndex[i], ip.length());

         break;
    }

change with it  

 for (i = 0; i < startIndex.length + 1;i++) {    
       case 2:
         outPut += ip.substring(startIndex[i] - 1, startIndex[i]);
         outPut += ip.substring(startIndex[i], ip.length());
         i++;
         break;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have this `sampleString = "127.1.1.254";` invoking `String[] yourArrayOfString = sampleString.split(".");` would result to `yourArrayOfString[0] = "127", yourArrayOfString[1] = "1", yourArrayOfString[2] = "1", yourArrayOfString[3] = "3"`.

And did you intentionally not put a `break;` on case 0 and 1?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to split a string by '.' character you can do the following -

```
String str[]= inputStr.split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not incrementing i at the end of the case 2 statement.

Why don't you use String.split()? e.g. ip.split("\.");